# PNG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png

[image]How to export a PNG file of a logo at a specific pixel dimension in illustrator? I exported many times but none keeps the ratio right. I want the logo to be exported as PNG[image] in square size. I took the artboard according to that. but my PNG gets stretched/reduced.

Comment: Only time its the same size as in illustrator is of you export at 72ppi

Comment: they gonna use it on their publication. 72 PPI will deteriorate the quality? right?

Comment: If it's for a *publication* why are you using PNG rather than supplying a vector file? PNG is typically an inappropriate format for print.

Comment: I am going to submit the vector file. PNG in a specific format (1200 px x 630 px ) is what they ask for. I submitted the original PNG(  export as). but I do not know how to get one in that specific size

Comment: Place the AI file into Photoshop as a Smart Object layer at whatever size/resolution you need.

Comment: Thank you. I am gonna do that. I do not understand why illustrator cant able to do that.

Comment: PPI is not a quality metric. Number of pixels are. 1200px by 630px at 72ppi and 1200px by 630px at 300ppi **is the exact same image**. Now illustrator is designed to use physical dimensions. So it only makes sense to change the PPI value if you definid the image to be some physical size such a cm or inches. Pixels can not really live side by side as units to physical dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a file 1200x630 px... Why are you making a square-proportion design?

You could export it, let's say, as a 1200x1200 px file, or 630x630px or whatever, but of course they WILL stretch the file.

---

Make an artboard on a new file with the correct proportion and decide what will happen to your design inside that file, if it is stretch, do it yourself, if it is a crop, then crop it yourself.

Illustrator has a deficient export dialog box, but you simply need a file on 1200x630px so using the export dialog at 72ppi will export the file at those px dimensions.

Comment: i love to experiment. when 1200 px  x630 px didn't work I tried it for square, circles... etc. Example I shared came from that. Scott's suggestion worked. read posts in adobe forum. illustrator cant do it. photoshop can. Thank you .